# How to create a buffer promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, buffer

I'm doing a challenge and I have to create a promise buffer, but I'm trying everything and nothing works. This is the link for the challenge: https://jsbin.com/pefagis/edit?html,js,output

Could someone help, I don't want the answer, I just need to know how to approach this solution.

Here's the function that I need to modify

```js
function bufferPromise(promiseFactoryFn, maxActive = 5) {
  // TODO: only call the promiseFactoryFn up to maxActive times
  // before buffering further calls.
  // The returned Promise should hide the buffering process.
  return (...args) => promiseFactoryFn(...args);
}
```

And here's the "solution" that I could think of

```js
function bufferPromise(promiseFactoryFn, maxActive = 5) {  
  const state = {
    active: 0,
    current: null,
    buffer: []
  }
  return (...args) => {
    state.active = state.active + 1;
    const getPromise = () => promiseFactoryFn(...args).then((response) => {
      state.active = state.active - 1;
      return response
    })
    
    if(!state.current){
      state.current = getPromise();
      return state.current;
    }
    
    if(state.active <= maxActive){      
      return getPromise()
    }else{
      state.buffer.push(getPromise);      
      return state.current
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) I'm afraid this is far too broad and open-ended. SO's Q&A format is for *specific* questions with specific answers.

Answer (score 3):

Challenge accepted.

```js
// The buffering function
const bufferPromise = (asyncFuntion, maxCount) => {
    
    // Keeps track of the number of currently running tasks
    let activeCount = 0;

    // Keeps track of waiting tasks (in the format { args, resolve, reject })
    const queue = [];



    // Enqueue the task or run it immediately
    const enqueueTask = (task) => {

        // If activeCount is less than maxCount
        // We can run more tasks than we do now
        if (activeCount < maxCount) {

            // Increase the counter
            activeCount++;

            // Run the new task immediately
            runTask(task);

        // We are running as many tasks as we can
        } else {

            // Put this new task into the queue
            queue.push(task);
        }
    };


    // Run the task
    const runTask = (task) => {

        // Run the async funtion
        asyncFuntion(task.args)

            // If successful resolve our promise as well
            .then(task.resolve)

            // If unsuccessful reject our promise as well
            .catch(task.reject)

            // When the task finishes (fails or succeeds) try to start the next task
            .finally(startNextTask);
    };


    // Tries to start the next task in the queue
    const startNextTask = () => {

        // Get the first element of an array
        const nextTask = queue.shift();


        // If it's truey
        // There is actually another task to run
        if (nextTask) {

            // Run that task
            runTask(nextTask);

        // There is no other task to run
        } else {

            // Decrease the counter
            activeCount--;
        }
    };



    // Return a funtion
    // which creates the task object and enqueues it
    // and wraps it all up in a promise
    return (args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => enqueueTask({args, resolve, reject}));
}




// == TESTING ==

// Async logging function for testing
// it logs the start, waits 2 seconds, logs the end and then resolves
const waitingConsoleFunction = (item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log("Started", item);

    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log("Resolved", item);
        resolve(item) 
    }, 2000);

});


// Testing the buffering funtion
const mappingFuntion = bufferPromise(waitingConsoleFunction, 2);

setTimeout(() => {
    // console.log(await Promise.all(
        [0,1,2,3,4,5].map(mappingFuntion)
    // ));
}, 0);

setTimeout(() => {
    // console.log(await Promise.all(
        [6,7,8,9,10,11,].map(mappingFuntion)
    // ));
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function bufferPromise(promiseFactoryFn, maxActive = 5) {  
  const queue = []; // holds all promises and handles each as a queue
  let activeCount = 0; // keeps track of the number of active promises 
  // dequeue => this function attempts to dequeue the queue of promises any time it
  // is called, it checks to see if maxActive has not been exceeded or if there are
  // still promises to be executed, then goes ahead to execute the current 
  // first promise, then on resolve, reject or an error decrements activeCount and
  // recursively calls dequeue again until either stopping condition as above is 
  // reached
  const dequeue = () => {
        if(activeCount >= maxActive) return false; // check maximum allowable
        if(!queue.length) return false; // check if there are any at all
        // get the first current promise object in a queue-based way
        const {args, resolve, reject } = queue.shift(); // destructure 
        // wrap it with a try/catch to catch possible errors on the created promise
        try {
           // increment activeCount then execute the main initial promise with the 
           // promiseFactoryFn
           promiseFactoryFn(args)
                .then((value) => {
                     resolve(value); // resolve the value
                     activeCount--; // decrement activeCount now that it resolved
                     dequeue(); // call dequeue to execute the next
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                     reject(err); // reject the err since there was one
                     activeCount--; // decrement activeCount now that it resolved
                     dequeue(); // call dequeue to execute the next
                })
        } catch(error) {
           // there was an error with the promise you pushed
           reject(error); // reject the err since there was one
           activeCount--; // decrement activeCount now that it resolved
           dequeue(); // call dequeue to execute the next
        }
        // successfully got an executable task from the queue within the maxActive 
        // and executed it
        return true;
  }
  // enqueue => this function will return a promise that pushes an object with the 
  // {args, resolve, reject} then attempts to perform a dequeue process
  const enqueue = (args) => {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              // adds to the queue
              queue.push({
                    args,
                    resolve,
                    reject
              });
              // tries to dequeue
              dequeue();
       });
  }
  return (args) => {
         return enqueue(args)
  }
```